# how to prevent postgres views calling redundant functions

Tags: postgresql

I have a view like this

```
create view v1 as select a,b,c,foo1(e,f) as f1, foo2(g,h) as f2 from t1;
```

when I do

```
select a from v1;
```

foo1 and foo2 are being called. This surprised me. (Other engines certainly do not). Foo1 anf foo2 are relatively expensive so I only want them evaluated if the user explicitly asks for them. Is there some way i can achieve this?

Comment: Use two views ?

Comment: Yes, there is probably room for optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good reason for this behaviour.

Every function in Postgres has a [volatility category](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html): `VOLATILE`, `STABLE`, or `IMMUTABLE`. These serve two purposes:

- They tell the query optimiser whether it's possible to omit a function call by re-using the output. For example, it knows `round()` will always return the same result for a given argument, while it can't make this assumption for something like `random()`.
- They tell the optimiser whether it's *safe* to omit a function call. If the function might have side-effects (e.g. inserting a record), then calls can't be optimised away without affecting the outcome, so in order to ensure predictable behaviour, such a function will always be evaluated.

The volatility category can't be automatically inferred, so Postgres defaults to the safest option: functions are `VOLATILE` unless declared otherwise, and so the query planner assumes that they might have side-effects. And even if such a function is buried in a view, and its result ignored by your query, it will still be executed.

If you declare your functions as `STABLE`, then they'll only be run when the result is actually needed.

(You can do this regardless of whether or not they actually *are* `STABLE`, but if they do have side-effects, it might not be in your best interests...)